# Where is this fountain (from Counter-Strike)?

Tags: where-on-earth, identify-this

The T-Spawn of the counter strike map de_inferno is based on a real place. Where is this fountain?

[image: photo of the unknown fountain]
[image: screenshot of the cs map]

Comment: So this is a photo of a place rather than how it appears in the game? `\-:`

Comment: @hippietrail I added a screenshot from the game

Comment: They don't tell you names of places, that you must (and _kill all_) in this game? :>

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This spot is based on [Mission San Juan Capistrano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_San_Juan_Capistrano), in California.  It has a Sacred Garden" that was developed in 1920. The four-bell campanario was erected a year after the bell tower at "The Great Stone Church" was toppled in the 1812 earthquake.

The photo of the garden that would match yours is found in the linked article above, as demonstrated with source below:

[image]

[(Source)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mission_San_Juan_Capistrano_4-5-05_100_6548.jpg)

There's also a [video comparing the map and the site](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQeH3NV1XtE).