# What city are these buildings in?

Tags: usa, where-on-earth, identify-this, architecture, cities

[image: *Motor Trend* November 1990]

This advertisement is from Motor Trend magazine - November 1990.

Additional Information: Yes, I am a fan of round and cylindrical buildings. I would like to see this grouping. I am sorry, I am new to this site and I did not know that I had to explain why I was interested in knowing where these where. I will keep that in mind next time. I thought it looked Texas-y. It sounds that it may be in Detroit and that is unfortunate :( I would never travel to there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with travel.

Comment: @Dorothy Similar questions have been [allowed previously](http://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=where+is+is%3Aquestion). Could you please explain why you think this question is very different from the other and should not be allowed?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke true, but this one is from ad printed in a trade magazine in 25 years ago, and are very likely an ad agency composite mock up of the background. Similar questions have been of travel photos.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke if one had to guess, this is ad agency alteration of a cityscape (probably the Detroit Renaissance Center; Detroit is the hq of Ford).

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke It's unclear why OP would find the buildings in the background an appealing travel-destination. Perhaps OP could have saved this question by saying: "These buildings are so *beautiful*, I want to travel there to see them with my own eyes." Jeg vet det er litt ukonsistent.

Comment: @Dorothy Ironically the Renaissance Center is a GM headquarters.  Ford is located in Dearborn, not Detroit proper.

Comment: @Fiksdal To each his own as they say. :)

Comment: @Karlson Yeah. I know what you're saying. The last part of my comment means "I know it's sorta inconsistent."

Comment: @Karlson... it wasn't when it was built in the 70's; that came much later, that GM acquired it. Designed by architect John Portman, it was conceived by Henry Ford II, financed primarily by the Ford Motor Company; it was, at the time, the largest private development, costing about half a billion dollars in 1971.

Comment: @Dorothy Yeah.  You're right.  in 1990 it was still a hotel and partly largely occupied by Ford.  GM bought it in 1996, which makes it even more ironic. :)

Comment: @Karlson the ultimate irony is that the Henry Ford Organization has a  massive archive, much of it digital and online, which is where the OP should address the question, rather than SE... just saying... https://www.thehenryford.org/collections-and-research/

Comment: @Dorothy this is a photo from a game: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/20465/2708 and not a travel photo either. I don't see the difference between: I saw a place in a game,  where is it? / I saw this place on my desktop wallpaper, where is it? / I saw this place in an ad, where is it? Besides, you gave some nice pointers in your comments which together could've formed an answer.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke true; I may have been hasty, and it did spark lots of engagement from SE regulars :-) We do love image challenges (I spent many an hour on the Norway fjord puzzle), although I don't know that my speculation is an answer.

Comment: Well I've found another photo of it, anyway: http://www.canstockphoto.com/futuristic-cylindrical-building-11605384.html

Comment: Building is the [Bonaventure Hotel in Los Angeles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westin_Bonaventure_Hotel); it's appeared in a ton of adverts/movies - one of the elevators even [has a plaque](https://www.flickr.com/photos/bytepusher/2502753671) mentioning its appearance in the movie True Lives. Architect is John Portman, who also did the RenCen in Detroit - hence the similarities.

Comment: Recommend a visit if you're into futuristic architecture: the main atrium is a cavernous space with a [maze of suspended walkways](https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/175/411031014_eddbe90295_z.jpg?zz=1) - a pedestrian version of LA's freeways, if you will. It also has capsule elevators and a rotating restaurant on top. Pretty interesting from a formal architecture point of view also - here's a clip from an academic program [critiquing the building as an example of postmodernist architecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hhyQ0HES8mM).

Comment: If you're at all interested in architecture, then absolutely! - Being a bit of a architecture/modernist fan myself, I made a point of staying at this hotel on a trip to LA some years back. I've also visited Portman buildings in Detroit, SF and Atlanta - Portman knows how to pull off [breathtaking hotel atriums](https://vpostrel.com/deep-glamour/hotel-week-how-john-portman-reinvented-the-lobby-with-visual-excitement). Not sure where I first saw the hotel myself - maybe album artwork for a late 80's [Kylie Album](http://www.music.lt/images/groups/1/18/Kylie_Minogue/1990labuildings1.jpg)?!

Comment: People travel for all sorts of reasons. I've gone far out of my way to see some buildings etc up close that I thought were very ugly but still interesting to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The city is **Los Angeles**. The building is presently the [Westin Bonaventure Hotel and Suites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westin_Bonaventure_Hotel), the largest hotel in the city, at 404 South Figueroa Street. It was designed by [John C. Portman, Jr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_C._Portman_Jr.) and built around 1975.

[image: The Westin Bonaventure Hotel and Suites]

Image above courtesy Google Maps and many more images [here](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/213287732323817179/).